# torch.matmul gives RuntimeError

Tags: pytorch, runtime

I have two tensors

```
t1=torch.Size([400, 32, 400])
t2= torch.Size([400, 32, 32])
```

when i excute this
`torch.matmul(t1,t2)`

i got this error RuntimeError:

> Expected tensor to have size 400 at dimension 1, but got size 32 for
> argument #2 'batch2' (while checking arguments for bmm)

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because the order of matrix multiplication is wrong.

It should be:

```py
a = torch.randn(400, 32, 400)
b = torch.randn(400, 32, 32)
out = torch.matmul(b, a) # You performed torch.matmul(a, b)
```

```py
# You can also do a simpler version of the matrix multiplication using the below code
out = b @ a
```

Comment: Thank you very much @planet, but I need to do torch.matmul(a,b), or out=a @ b, is there a good way of reshaping so that i can do this

Comment: In that case, you could do this: `a = torch.randn(400, 32, 400).permute(0, 2, 1)` and then you can do `out = a @ b`